# How to print List<Complex> to array of x+iy format [ Using Apache Common Math - Complex ]

Tags: java, apache, complex-numbers

I was trying to print all n roots of a complex number in x+iy format . I am using [Apache Common Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) . Here is my code:

```
package complex;
import static java.lang.String.format;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex;
import org.apache.commons.math3.complex.ComplexFormat;
public class Do 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ComplexFormat complexFormat = new ComplexFormat();
    Complex r = new Complex(6.3,9.6);
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(r.nthRoot(8));
    List list2 = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=list.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        String c = (list.get(i).toString());
       list2.add(c);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list2.toArray()));
}
}
```

My output was ok

Output :

```
run:
[[(1.346389790047983, 0.16747833178910174), (0.8336162865533764,     1.070466414773145), (-0.16747833178910165, 1.346389790047983), (-1.070466414773145, 0.8336162865533764), (-1.346389790047983, -0.16747833178910157), (-0.8336162865533766, -1.070466414773145), (0.1674783317891015, -1.346389790047983), (1.070466414773145, -0.8336162865533766)]]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

But I want this in a array or list of x+iy format . I have tried both `complexFormat.Parse()` and `complexFormat.format()` on each list item , but that case generates exception.

Would you please explain better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `ComplexFormat` as follows, calling the `format()` method on a single number of type `Complex` each time:

```
formatter = new ComplexFormat();
for (Complex c : list2)
{
    System.out.println(formatter.format(c));
}
```

This code should replace your current line `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list2.toArray()));` and you'll be good to go...

#### but...

you probably don't need the hassle of creating and using `list2`, just set up `list` as a `List<Complex>` rather than `List<Object>` and use that directly.  So a final version of cut down code could be :

```
package complex;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex;
import org.apache.commons.math3.complex.ComplexFormat;
public class Do 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    ComplexFormat complexFormat = new ComplexFormat();
    Complex r = new Complex(6.3,9.6);
    List<Complex> list = r.nthRoot(8);
    for (Complex c : list)
    {
        System.out.println(complexFormat.format(c));
    }
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
1.34638979 + 0.1674783318i
0.8336162866 + 1.0704664148i
-0.1674783318 + 1.34638979i
-1.0704664148 + 0.8336162866i
-1.34638979 - 0.1674783318i
-0.8336162866 - 1.0704664148i
0.1674783318 - 1.34638979i
1.0704664148 - 0.8336162866i
```

Note - the documentation for `ComplexFormat` is [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/ComplexFormat.html) and, in particular, you should notice that if you [instantiate it with no arguments](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/ComplexFormat.html#ComplexFormat%28%29) (as I do above), it defaults to the `x + yi` format.  If you want to play with the format, you pass parameters when you instantiate the formatter, as covered in those docs.